# how does materials work exported from json

Tags: three.js

I have a model of low poly tree made in blender and then exported in .json with three.js blender exporter. [Here](http://pastebin.com/J7pVVRbt) is this json file. You can see that it contain 4 materials but the uvs array is empty for some reason. When I load it in my application using JSONLoader on r74dev

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load('tree.json', ( geometry, materials ) => {
    materials.map((material) => {
        material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
    });
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    this.scene.add(mesh);

});
```

it appear with messed colors (left is how it looks in my threejs application, right is from blender).

[image]

But can some one explain me how the materials are applied here. UVs array in JSON is empty and the result mesh does not have any children and `geometry.faceVertexUvs` is also empty so how then threejs know when each material should be applied?

[image]

Also If I load it in [theejs editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) it will appear all black - without any material, why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using diffuse color in the material like this,

[image]

Check UVs option to get uv and uncheck Vertex Colors to get `diffuse color`

[image]

Comment: thanx, that helped to fix colors but still `uvs` is empty array in JSON and the mesh `geometry.faceVertexUvs` is also empty - how then three.js know where to apply materials? The JSON is now look like this - http://pastebin.com/70hDptJ1

Comment: Did you generate UVs in blender?https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/unwrapping.html

Comment: no, I don't and in JSON the uvs is empty but materials somehow are applied correctly and I can't understand - how?

Comment: yesyes, because applying color doesnt require UVs, It usually used with image textures.

If you apply image texture like `map` or `normalMap`, it is necessary.

Comment: When you apply texture in Blender, you should have UVs in your blender.